# Snowflake last "valid" value in a window function

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I am changing a column value by lagging the last valid value, in case the current column value is a specific value.
The problem is, if I am fixing this value, I need to fix also 3 other columns with the value they had in the last valid row with where I fetched the value of the main column.

I got stuck in the last part.

```
SELECT coalesce(NULLIF(NETWORK_NAME,'FALLBACK_CASE'), LAG(NULLIF(NETWORK_NAME,'FALLBACK_CASE')) IGNORE NULLS OVER (partition by adid order by created_at asc)) NETWORK_NAME_FIX,
NETWORK_NAME,
CASE WHEN NETWORK_NAME_FIX != NETWORK_NAME THEN LAST_VALUE(CAMPAIGN_NAME) OVER (partition by adid, network_name_fix order by created_at asc) ELSE CAMPAIGN_NAME END CAMPAIGN_NAME_FIX,
CAMPAIGN_NAME, CREATIVE_NAME, ADGROUP_NAME, MATCH_TYPE,
CREATED_AT, DATE_MONTH, DATE_WEEK
FROM b
```

`NETWORK_NAME_FIX` works as expected, but `CAMPAIGN_NAME_FIX` doesn't, because it does not recursively check itself but always look at `CAMPAIGN_NAME` and so fix only few cases.
The same logic of `CAMPAIGN_NAME` should be applied to the next 2 columns.

I am not very familiar with window functions, I wish I could do something like:
"give me the last_value `campaign_name` had the last time `network_name_fix` and `network_name` were equal."

Something like this in pseudo code, that is not a valid statement:

```
last_value(campaign_name) over (partition by adid order by created_at where network_name = network_name_fix)
```

Tabular data example of the desired output:

Let's assume the fallback case to be that I don't want `network_name` = `x`

| id | network_name_fix | network_name | campaign_name_fix | campaign_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | "a" | "a" | "abc" | "abc" |
| 12 | "g" | "g" | "pow" | "pow" |
| 12 | "g" | "x" | "pow" | "xuz" |
| 12 | "g" | "x" | "pow" | "xuz" |
| 12 | "p" | "p" | "trz" | "trz" |
| 12 | "p" | "x" | "trz" | "vum" |
| 12 | "a" | "a" | "abc" | "abc" |

Comment: Sample data will greatly help your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with some fancy SQL and a self-join, but what would make it much cleaner and simpler is a new window function that holds on to multiple last known good (LKG) values. What's needed is a window function with a parameter that defines what's "good" for the purposes of LKG, and what values to hold on to if they're needed later.

Fortunately, Snowflake allows the creation of user defined window functions though UDTFs, user defined table functions. Let's start with the UDTF first:

```
create or replace function LKG_VALUES(LKG_CONDITION boolean, VALS object)
returns table (LKG_VALS object)
language javascript
strict immutable
as
$$
{
    initialize: function (argumentInfo, context) {
        this.lkg = {};
    },
    processRow: function (row, rowWriter, context) {
        if(row.LKG_CONDITION) this.lkg = row.VALS;
        rowWriter.writeRow({LKG_VALS: this.lkg});
    },
}
$$;
```

This function's first parameter is a Boolean that specifies what's good for the purposes of the LKG values. The second parameter is an object that holds on to those values when needed. Now we can use this function.

First, let's create some sample data:

```
create or replace table T1 (id int,
                            network_name string,
                            campaign_name string, 
                            created_at timestamp);

insert into T1 select 12,'a','abc',current_timestamp();
insert into T1 select 12,'g','pow',current_timestamp();
insert into T1 select 12,'x','xuz',current_timestamp();
insert into T1 select 12,'x','xuz',current_timestamp();
insert into T1 select 12,'p','trz',current_timestamp();
insert into T1 select 12,'x','vum',current_timestamp();
insert into T1 select 12,'a','abc',current_timestamp();
```

Now let's call the function and use it to get our LKG values:

```
select   ID
        ,LKG_VALS:NETWORK_NAME::string NETWORK_NAME_FIXED
        ,NETWORK_NAME
        ,CAMPAIGN_NAME
        ,LKG_VALS:CAMPAIGN_NAME::string CAMPAIGN_NAME_FIXED
        ,CREATED_AT
from     T1,
  table(LKG_VALUES(NETWORK_NAME <> 'x', 
                   object_construct( 'NETWORK_NAME', NETWORK_NAME
                                    ,'CAMPAIGN_NAME', CAMPAIGN_NAME
                                   ))
        over (partition by ID order by CREATED_AT)
       )
;
```

The `,table(...` wrapping the LKG_VALUES table function is simply how UDTFs have to be called (lateral joins to table functions). The `over` and `partition by` work the same way as regular window functions (except if partition by is omitted, so don't omit it).

We can see in the use of this function that the expression `NETWORK_NAME <> 'x'` indicates when we have a Last Known Good, LKG condition. We use `object_construct` to hold on to one or more values (if it's just one, `lag()` works better). We can then refer to those values using Snowflake's JSON parsing methods, `<COLUMN_NAME>:<json_path>::<data_type>`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am not an expert so it will take a while for me to digest and understand the code, I will test it soon :)